# Get freeswitch events using ZMQ

Tags: c, zeromq, freeswitch

I want to get events from freeswitch using ZMQ. I have enable `mod_event_socket` and `mod_event_zmq` in freeswitch and I am using following code to receive events but I am not getting anything.

```
#include <zmq.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>

static char * s_recv (void *socket) {
    char buffer [256];
    int size = zmq_recv (socket, buffer, 255, 0);
    if (size == -1)
        return NULL;
    if (size > 255)
        size = 255;
    buffer [size] = 0;
    return strdup (buffer);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv [])
{
    // Socket to talk to server
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new ();
    void *subscriber = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_SUB);
    int rc = zmq_connect (subscriber, "tcp://10.50.202.169:5556");
    assert (rc == 0);

    char filter[256] = {0};
    rc = zmq_setsockopt (subscriber, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE,
    "", 256);
    assert (rc == 0);

    // Process 100 updates
    int update_nbr;
    for (update_nbr = 0; update_nbr < 100; update_nbr++) {
        char *string = s_recv (subscriber);
        printf("%s",string);
        free (string);
    }

    zmq_close (subscriber);
    zmq_ctx_destroy (context);
    return 0;
}
```

I am using default configurations for both these modules of freeswitch.

Comment: where is your question ?

Comment: I want to ask, why is this not receiving anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

was the zmq connection to FreeSWITCH successful?
did FreeSWITCH actually load `mod_event_zmq` module?

Comment: Yes. mod_event_zmq is loaded successfully

Comment: Did I use filter correctly? For now, I want to get everything.

Comment: seems to be alright, but needs digging deeper, probably looking up in the sources.

Comment: Thanks. I solved the issue by putting `0` as last parameter of  `zmq_setsockopt`.